# Apply an accumulative function to each column of a dataset

Tags: dataset, filtering

Given a dataset with many columns, how can apply a function (in this case `Count[Missing_]`) to each column?

```
datasets["MSFT"][Count[_Missing], "PX_VOLUME"]
```

will work, but only for the `"PX_VOLUME"` column.

For example,

```
datasets["MSFT"][Count[_Missing], #]& /@ cols
```

would do the trick, but is there a more *built-in* way of doing it?

Edit. What I'd like to end up with is something similar to

```
{keys,
 datasets["MSFT"][Count[_Missing], #] & /@ keys/Length[datasets["MSFT"]] // N} 
    // Transpose // TableForm
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Please provide some minimal, but complete enough for readers to test, set of example data. In the meantime, *read the documentation*, have a look at `Map` and `Transpose`.

Comment: Ok I _could_ map a function that would loop on all columns, but that's not very elegant.

Comment: What's "not very elegant" about `Count[#,_Missing]&/@Transpose@<your matrix here>`?

Comment: I just have the feeling that `Dataset` would provide an interface to do it by itself. If I simply map the function, then I lose `Dataset` environment I was working on (ie. no more column names, just a plain list)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In *Mathematica* version 10.0 this operation is awkward, but version 10.1 offers an improvement.

I will use the Titanic dataset in following examples:

```
$ds = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}];
```

**Version 10.0**

In version 10.0, it is awkward to apply a subquery to every column in a rectangular dataset.  Here is one way to apply the *All* operator to each column:

```
$ds[Normal @ $ds[1 /* AssociationMap[#[[1]] -> Query[All, #[[1]]] &]]]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Alternatively, we can replace `All` with the desired `Count` aggregation:

```
$ds[Normal @ $ds[1 /* AssociationMap[#[[1]] -> Query[Count[_Missing], #[[1]]] &]]]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

This same pattern can be used for any columnar aggregation.  Here is `CountDistinct`:

```
$ds[Normal @ $ds[1 /* AssociationMap[#[[1]] -> Query[CountDistinct, #[[1]]]&]]]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

**Version 10.1**

Fortunately, the situation has improved somewhat in version 10.1:

```
$ds[Transpose]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

```
$ds[Transpose /* Query[All, CountDistinct]]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

```
$ds[Transpose /* Query[All, Count[_Missing]]]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

This last can also be expressed using `Map`:

```
$ds[Transpose /* Map[Count[_Missing]]]
```

Or it can be expressed in a slightly more succinct form at the cost of two separate query executions:

```
$ds[Transpose][All, Count[_Missing]]
```

Incidentally, the `Transpose` query operator is compiled down to the  undocumented but useful function `` GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose `` which can transpose a list of associations.

**Tricks in the Style of SQL**

In the SQL world, aggregations like this are sometimes performed by first transforming the raw data elements and then applying some aggregation operator to those transformed results.  Such a trick can be used to good effect to count the missing values:

```
$ds[Total, All, Replace[{_Missing -> 1, _ -> 0}]]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

The disadvantage of tricks like these is that they must be designed on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 3):

Illustrating Rasher's suggestions for your convenience with some data set. Just create anything for the sake to demonstrate counting:

```
dset = ElementData[#, "SoundSpeed"] & /@ ElementData[] // 
  ArrayReshape[#, {10, 4}] &
```

this looks like this `dset // TableForm`

```
Count[#, _Missing] & /@ Transpose @ dset

(*{3, 1, 2, 1}*)
```

Cannot think of anything simpler than this. 
This answer only for purpose of illustration at your convenience, please vote for Rasher.

Comment: This works, but the "dset" is not a Dataset.

Comment: @mgamer `Count[_Missing] /@ Transpose[dataset]` or equivalent `Transpose[dataset][All, Count[_Missing]]` are slightly shorter. These will both work on `Dataset` objects